# Need Help in a django empty popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, iframe

I want to create a popup in a django template but the popup appears empty
This is my code so far:

```
<input type="button"  value="{{ account.account_id }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="myid"/>

<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              <iframe src="{% url 'Trinity:accountinfo'%}?id={{account.account_id}}" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
```

But when i am using the iframe the code is working. Here is the example :

`<iframe src="{% url 'Trinity:accountinfo'%}?id=123509817994125" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`

But I want to pass the  dynamically value of `id` not hard coded.
Any idea would appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: What does the `iframe src` (and the `button value`) look like when you load the page? Does it have a value in it? I think you may want  `{{ account.id }}` instead of what you have. I would have to see your `Account` model to be sure.

Comment: @RobL    Actually it is about the way how to pass the id dinamically to the src of iframe  .The button has a value and has the account id number

Comment: So you will have to use AJAX to `load` the iframe. Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: <div id = "targetDiv"></div>
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#targetDiv').load('accountinfo.html');
});
</script>        something like this @RobL

Comment: Something like that. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: but still i don't know how to  pass the id.

Comment: I posted an answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your template:
First, give the `iframe` an `id` to make it easier, e.g., `<iframe id="my_frame" ...`

Next, give the button a way to pass the `account_id` to the script, e.g., `<input type="button" data-account_id={{ account.account_id }}" ...`

```
<script>

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var account_id = button.data('account_id')
    $("#my_frame").attr('src','{% url 'Trinity:accountinfo'%}?id=' + account_id);
})

</script>
```

I haven't tested this, but it or something like it is what you want. Give it a try and see if it helps.

Comment: var account_id = button.data('account_id');     this  gets an undefined value

Comment: Hmm, in the button, what is the value of `data-account_id=` ?